Airship Notification received but not displaying in phone (Android specifically)
I get the log message received from Airship, but notification not showing in phone. I am using  "@ua/react-native-airship" it is working in iOS but not in android.
Below is the response I got from Airship.
Object {
  "data": Object {
    "com.urbanairship.metadata": "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uX2lkIjoxLCJ0aW1lIjoxNzEyMjI3MTgxNzg4LCJwdXNoX2lkIjoiYTRmMDA4YjAtZjI2Zi0xMWVlLWFjYjctMDAwMGExYWNlMzdiIiwiY2FtcGFpZ25zIjp7ImNhdGVnb3JpZXMiOltdfSwiY29udGV4dCI6e319",
    "com.urbanairship.push.ALERT": "Congratulations! You've successfully configured Android Push.",
    "com.urbanairship.push.APID": "a7e006b7-1a41-4b68-b950-0e3f5cefee0b",
    "com.urbanairship.push.CANONICAL_PUSH_ID": "a4f008b0-f26f-11ee-acb7-0000a1ace37b",
    "com.urbanairship.push.PUSH_ID": "a4f511c0-f26f-11ee-b31c-02420ecfd1d8",
  },
  "from": "1068392163023",
  "messageId": "0:1712227181868860%84526986f9fd7ecd",
  "sentTime": 1712227181845,
  "ttl": 2419200,
}


Are you sure app and user notifications are enabled? I found this doc section about Android troubleshooting. Maybe it can help you with your problem

yes I can confirm it is enabled, notification are working fine from firebase console, but not working for airship.

can you post your code

Can you tell me which code you asking for?
